# Why does my CONCAT function in MySQL result in a syntax error?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT CONCAT(PurchaseID, OnlineType, ShopLocation) As Purchase
FROM PURCHASE 
WHERE PurchaseID IN 
(
  SELECT PurchaseID
  FROM ONLINEPURCHASE 
(
  WHERE PurchaseID IN (SELECT PurchaseID 
  FROM WALKINPURCHASE
)
);
```

I'm trying to put a concat to display PurchaseID that are entered in both OnlineType and Shoplocation

```
Error
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(
WHERE PurchaseID IN (SELECT PurchaseID 
FROM WALKINPURCHASE
```

Comment: Your CONCAT usage is alright. But your second parenthesis are not. I'd also suggest you to take a look at the JOIN utility.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code. But, if you're determined to solve this in MySQL, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one **)** too much

```
SELECT CONCAT(PurchaseID, OnlineType, ShopLocation) As Purchase
FROM PURCHASE 
WHERE PurchaseID IN 
(
  SELECT PurchaseID
  FROM ONLINEPURCHASE     
  WHERE PurchaseID IN 
    (SELECT PurchaseID 
    FROM WALKINPURCHASE
    )
);
```

You should try to align the code, so that you can see the blocks in one view.

But you should try this Select statement

```
SELECT CONCAT(p.PurchaseID, op.OnlineType, p.ShopLocation) As Purchase
FROM PURCHASE p 
  inner join  ONLINEPURCHASE op 
    ON p.PurchaseID = op.PurchaseID 
  inner join WALKINPURCHASE w 
    ON op.PurchaseID  = w.PurchaseID;
```

Comment: ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'p.OnlineType' in 'field list'
Is it because my OnlineType is from ONLINEPURCHASE table?

Comment: Yes, i changed it to op.OnlineType. I can only speculate from your Select query, i don't know the structure of  your tabes

Comment: thanks! I manage to fix it by changing p.Shoplocation to w.ShopLocation. It kind of works !

Comment: Can i add words or symbolds in the concat brackets?

Comment: yes, you write simply   CONCAT(p.PurchaseID, ' my text ',op.OnlineType,' ', w.ShopLocation) and you can add more